# prevent react-router from detecting location change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React/Redux based application, I have implemented logout like following

In `reducers/index.js` where I do `combineReducers`, I have created an app level reducer called `appReducer`. There I check for `LOGOUT` action and then return `undefined`.

All this works fine. What I want to do is, that for `LOGOUT` action, I also want to clear `localStorage` and redirect to login page. Please note that I want to redirect native browser way, not using react-router. If I do `window.location = '/'`. First its detected by react-router and I see login page for a bit and then it refreshes which is a bit odd.

Is there a way to prevent react-router from being notified on location change!?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent it completely but you can control it with the access to 
history.listen function.

With React-Router 4 you can wrap top level components using the HOC withRouter.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

This allows accessing this.props.history and controlling it

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      //here you can control the location change
    });
  }

  render() {
     return (
         </div>
      );
  }
}
```

And you also have the **listenBefore** event on the history object and you can use this event to control the navigation and add your own custom navigation logic:

```
history.listenBefore( (location, done) => doSomething(location).then(done) )
```

Comment: listenBefore isn't a function on history

Comment: @earl3s Seems that is now called .block() (https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/379)